# How can I extract all the keyframes from an MP4 video using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, extract, keyframe, mkv

I would like to extract all keyframes from a video in BMP format for further processing. I managed to investigate this command:

```
ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i videofile.mp4 -vf select='eq(pict_type\,I),setpts=N/(25*TB)' -q 1  ./%09d.bmp
```

It works on all video files, except on MP4 and MKV files. Instead of it extracts all frames from the MP4 files, and additionally I got a lot of error messages:

```
[h264 @ 0x90d80a0] concealing 1200 DC, 1200 AC, 1200 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x90c4ce0] concealing 1200 DC, 1200 AC, 1200 MV errors in B frame
[h264 @ 0x90d80a0] concealing 1200 DC, 1200 AC, 1200 MV errors in B frame
[h264 @ 0x90d7500] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x90d7500] concealing 1200 DC, 1200 AC, 1200 MV errors in P frame
```

What can I do to make it work also on MP4 files, or what other utility / method (mencoder / vlc) should I use to achieve my goal?

Comment: It should work without the `-skip_frame nokey`.

Comment: Yes, I knew that, but in that case the process is really slow.

Comment: I suggest filing a bug report (https://ffmpeg.org/bugreports.html): `-skip_frame nokey` confuses h264 decoder.

Comment: I know this question was asked over a year before I'm writing this, but this sort of question might get a better response on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).